# How many substantially different ways are there to cut a convex polygon to n convex polygons?

Tags: geometry

We want to divide a convex polygon $C$ into $n$ convex pieces.

If $n=2$, the only way is to use one straight line through $C$.

If $n=3$, we have two options:

- Two striaght lines through $C$, or -
- Three rays originating from a point in the interior of $C$.

Although each of these options contains infinitely many different divisions, if we consider only the number of cut-lines then all cuts fall into one of these two options.

How many options do we have for general $n$?

Comment: Each such cutting gives some graph where result polygons are vertices, and two vertices are adjacent if they share an edge. Isn't the class of graph we can get this way simply planar connected graphs?

Comment: This makes sense. So the number of ways to cut is just the number of planar graphs over $n$ vertices?

Comment: I would say connected and unlabeled planar graphs. But i'm not sure if cuttings and graphs are isomorphic. Especially I'm not sure if for each such graph exists proper cutting of a polygon.

Comment: Since you permit half-lines (rays originating from...), for n=3, you also have a third options: a straight line and a ray originating from a point on the line. Or, do you have a reason to treat this the same as three rays ?

Comment: Similarly, for n=4, if you have a straight cut and two rays originating from it, how many ways does that allow ? Do you count the two rays on the same side as a different case than one ray on each side ?

Comment: @Jeffrey I thought of only counting the number of lines. But now I think that this might be trivial.

Comment: The interesting problem to me would be: how many different graphs can the cutting lines (and half-lines) create. Where different is define as "not being isomorphic". Then, f(2) = 1, f(3) =  3. I still have to think about f(4) and the general solution.